# PHP JSON looping through nested arrays labelled ARRAY[0], ARRAY[1] etc

Tags: php, arrays, json, loops

I am being sent loopy reading about looping through JSON arrays!

I have decoded a JSON string. It contains orders for pizzas and customer info. Each order is in an array, the first one called Array[0], the second Array[1], etc.
Within each array there is [products] which contains Array[0] with the details of the first pizza, Array[1] with the details of the second etc.

I cannot for the life of me figure out how to access the values in the [products] array.

Within [products] one of the values is a JSON string itself but I've got nowhere near worrying about that yet!

Print_R gives me this:

Array [0] => Array( [order_number] => 568

```
    [products] => Array ( [0] => Array ( 
                  [item_no] => 1 
                  [item_name] => Full Veggie Pizza
                  [qty] => 2 
                  [woofood_meta] => {"original_price":"9.0"} )
                  
                  [1] => Array ( 
                  [item_no] => 2
                  [item_name] => Full Veggie Pizza 
                  [qty] => 1 
                  [woofood_meta] => {"extra_options":{"Extras": 
                                   [{"id":61,"price":"\u00a30.50",
                                  
                  "price_float":0.5,"category":"Extras","name":"Jalape\u00f1os",
                                     
                   "hide_prices":false}]},"extra_options_price":0.5,"original_price":"9.0"} )
                  
                  [2] => Array ( 
                  [item_no] => 3
                  [item_name] => Full Veggie Pizza 
                  [qty] => 1 
                  [woofood_meta] => {"extra_options":{"Extras": 
                                    [{"id":57,"price":"\u00a30.50",
                                      "price_float":0.5,"category":"Extras","name":"Extra 
                                        veg 1)","hide_prices":false},
```

{"id":61,"price":"\u00a30.50","price_float":0.5,"category":"Extras","name":"Jalape\u00f1os","hide_prices":false},
{"id":62,"price":"\u00a30.00","price_float":0,"category":"Extras","name":"Chillies","hide_prices":false}]},
"additional_comments":"Pineapple","extra_options_price":1,"original_price":"9.0"} )

```
                  [3] => Array ( 
                  [item_no] => 4 
                  [item_name] => Pepperoni Pizza 
                  [qty] => 1 
                  [woofood_meta] => {"original_price":"8.50"} )  
                  
                  [date_to_deliver] => 2020-07-25 00:00 
                  [time_to_deliver] => 19:00 
                  [full_name] => Freda People 
                  [address] => 22 New St 
                  [city] => Newtown
                  [postcode] => NT6 6NT 
                  [phone] => 07123 456 789 
                  [email] => freda@gmail.com 
                  [customer_note] => Beware of the dog )
```

Array [1] => Array( [order_number] => 569 //This is how the next set of arrays begins

I can echo all the name and address details but nothing from the [products] array.

My code is:

```
                          $url = 'orders(1).json';
                          $jsonobj = file_get_contents($url);

                          $arr = json_decode($jsonobj, true);
            
         $element = $arr;
         
         foreach($arr as $element) {
             for($i=0;$i<count($element.products['$i']);$i++){
        echo $element ['order_number']; "<br>";
        echo $element ['products[$i].qty']; "<br>";
        echo $element ['products[$i].item_name']; "<br>";
        echo $element ['products[$i].woofood_meta.name']; "<br>";
        echo $element ['products[$i].woofood_meta.additional_comments']; "<br>";
        echo $element ['date_to_deliver']; "<br>";
        echo $element ['time_to_deliver']; "<br>";
        echo $element ['full_name']; "<br>";
                                 
                                                             } 
                                    }
```

An array from the json as requested:

[{"order_number":"573","products":[{"item_no":1,"item_name":"Neapolitan Pizza","qty":"1","woofood_meta":"{"original_price":"9.50"}"},{"item_no":2,"item_name":"Margherita Pizza","qty":"1","woofood_meta":"{"extra_options":{"Extras":[{"id":59,"price":"\u00a31.00","price_float":1,"category":"Extras","name":"Extra cheese 1","hide_prices":false}]},"extra_options_price":1,"original_price":"7.50"}"},{"item_no":3,"item_name":"Cheesy Garlic Bread (v)","qty":"1","woofood_meta":"{"original_price":"4.5"}"}],"date_to_deliver":"2020-07-31 00:00","time_to_deliver":"19:00","full_name":"XXXX XXXX","address":"ZZZZ ZZZZ","city":"VVVVVVVV","postcode":"123 456","phone":"1234567890","email":"xx@yy.com","customer_note":"we are still shielding. Thanks for all your help"}

Comment: A word of advice: ignore the fact that this is from JSON, and learn the basics of accessing PHP arrays.

Comment: Share a sample JSON, then we might be able to help

Comment: There's the print_r in the OP, tried to post a line here but too long.

Comment: @Anthony Please always present your array/object data as either `var_export()` output or a json string -- this way volunteers can instantly copy-paste your sample data into their testing environment and get cracking on resolving your issue.  When you use `print_r()` or `var_dump()` then volunteers have to waste time preparing the data into something that they can run code on.  (No need to apologize for not knowing this, I am just helping you to understand how to write clearer questions and receive better support faster.) After pasting into the question, highlight the text, then press Ctrl+K.

Comment: I've added a line to the OP. Thanks for the heads-up!

Comment: `foreach($array as $a){ foreach($a['products'] as $p){ foreach($p as $j){ $phpArray = json_decode($j['woofood_meta']); } } }`

Comment: I shall have a go with it tomorrow and tell you my results. It's way past midnight here so thank you so  much and good night.

Comment: Thanks, StackSlave, that did it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a lack of knowledge on working with arrays, and so let's first review that.

```
$arr = [0, 1, 2];
```

Firstly arrays are 0 indexed, meaning to an array with a length of 3, will have the index's 0, 1, 2. So to access the first piece of data we would want to enter the index 0.

```
$arr[0] = 0;
```

Now often with API and JSON data there will be what are called nested arrays :

```
$arr = [ 0, [ 1, 2 ] 3 ];
```

So how do we get into all the elements now? Well we simply apply the same principle, of first accessing the initial index, then accessing the index of the data we want. Ex:

```
$arr[1][0] = 1
```

First we are going into index 1 which is our nested array: [ 1, 2 ] then we are using the next bracket to index into what piece of data we would like.

And this is basically how indexing arrays work.

Also a sidenote, often with foreach() loops you can format the key and value from the JSON data as such.

```
foreach ($arr as $key=>$value) {
  $_SESSION[$key] = $value;
}
```

I heavily recommend practicing this and getting it down, as this is just a core concept of programming in most languages. And apply this to your current issue!

Comment: Thanks for the examples, it's really helped. I can see I need to learn about arrays rather than concentrating on the JSON!

Comment: I did it! Thanks for the help. Combining your mini-tutorial and stackslaves code snippet I got there in the end.

Comment: @AnthonyNewall Glad to hear! It can be rough debugging or learning new concepts but it always pays off in the end.